# Problem evaluating inverse laplace transform with sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Why the function plot of sympy is showing an empty axes without errors?

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
import sympy as sp
from sympy.physics.units.quantities import Quantity
import sys
sys.set_int_max_str_digits(0)

%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'

def laplace(f):
    s = symbols('s')
    t = symbols ('t',real=True)
    return sp.laplace_transform(f, t, s, noconds=True)

def ilaplace(F):
    s = symbols('s')
    t = symbols ('t',real=True)
    return sp.inverse_laplace_transform(F, s, t,noconds=True).evalf().nsimplify()
```

```
s,n = symbols('s,n')

Rc= sp.Rational(1)
Rp= sp.Rational(1,2)
Cw= sp.Rational(1,5)
Cs= sp.Rational(1,200)
Cl= sp.Rational(1,5)
T= sp.Rational(4)
P1= sp.Rational(5)
Q= sp.Rational(1,3)

t = symbols('t',real = True)
```

```
Ct=(1/Cl + 1/Cw + 1/Cs)**(-1)
A=1 / (Rp*Ct)
B=Rc
C=1/Cs + Rc/(Rp*Ct)
D=(1/(Rp*Cs))*(1/Cl+1/Cw)
```

```
r1=(-C+sqrt(C**2-4*B*D))/(2*B)
r2=(-C-sqrt(C**2-4*B*D))/(2*B)
```

```
P=Sum(laplace(P1*(sp.Heaviside(t-n*T)-sp.Heaviside(t-T*(n+Q)))),[n,0,1])
G=(s+A)/((s-r1)*(s-r2))
```

```
V=(G*P)
v=ilaplace(V)
v=v
v
```

```
grafV1=plot(v,(t,0,50),xlabel="t",ylabel="V(t)",legends=True,line_color="green")
```

[obtained plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llREJ.png)

Is someway to make  the function works?

Pd: I use Colab and don't know how to paste the code so i use the Code Block for copy it.

Comment: There are missing variables, so we can't execute your code... What are `Cl, Cw, Cs, Rp, Rc, ..., n, ....`? When asking a question, make sure the code you post can be executed...

Comment: I copy two times the first code block of my code, I already changed it. thanks for the advice

Comment: Given the answer that I provided, I'm going to change the title of this question to better reflect the problem, so that other people dealing with Inverse Laplace Transform can benefit from this...

Answer (score 3):

> Why the function plot of sympy is showing an empty axes without errors?

That's a bug. It should raise an error because the `plot` function is unable to evaluate your expression.

**Welcome to a lesson in expression manipulation**

Let's look closely at what you are trying to plot:

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *

def laplace(f):
    s = symbols('s')
    t = symbols ('t',real=True)
    return sp.laplace_transform(f, t, s, noconds=True)

def ilaplace(F):
    s = symbols('s')
    t = symbols ('t',real=True)
    return sp.inverse_laplace_transform(F, s, t,noconds=True).evalf().nsimplify()

s,n = symbols('s,n')

Rc= sp.Rational(1)
Rp= sp.Rational(1,2)
Cw= sp.Rational(1,5)
Cs= sp.Rational(1,200)
Cl= sp.Rational(1,5)
T= sp.Rational(4)
P1= sp.Rational(5)
Q= sp.Rational(1,3)

t = symbols('t',real = True) 

Ct=(1/Cl + 1/Cw + 1/Cs)**(-1)
A=1 / (Rp*Ct)
B=Rc
C=1/Cs + Rc/(Rp*Ct)
D=(1/(Rp*Cs))*(1/Cl+1/Cw)

r1=(-C+sqrt(C**2-4*B*D))/(2*B)
r2=(-C-sqrt(C**2-4*B*D))/(2*B)

P=Sum(laplace(P1*(sp.Heaviside(t-n*T)-sp.Heaviside(t-T*(n+Q)))),[n,0,1])
G=(s+A)/((s-r1)*(s-r2))

V=(G*P)
v=ilaplace(V)
v
```

[image]

As you can see, the Inverse Laplace Transforms (ILT, from now on) were not evaluated. I suspect the main cause is the inability of SymPy to factorize the quadratic term in the denominator. Also, the summations inside the ILTs might not help.

Hence, we have to manually evaluate them! We will compute the ILT of rational functions following [the approach of this book](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MTH_225_Differential_Equations/8%3A_Laplace_Transforms/8.2%3A_The_Inverse_Laplace_Transform).

We are going to expand the summations inside the ILTs:

```py
v = v.replace(lambda t: isinstance(t, Sum), lambda t: t.doit())
v
```

[image]

At the time of writing this, SymPy 1.12 is the latest release. Running `v.doit()` to evaluate the ILTs is going to take forever. I've already checked that master branch of SymPy is able to compute it, so for future sympy version all we need to do is:

```py
from spb import plot
plot(v_time, modules="sympy", ylabel="v(t)")
```

For SymPy 1.12 (and earlier), we have to manually compute it...

The expression contains 4 ILTs, but only 2 are different from each other:

```py
# find all occurences of ILT
ilt = list(v.find(InverseLaplaceTransform))
ilt
```

[image]

Note that we can rewrite each ILT as:

[image]

The first ILT contains 2 time delays terms. The second one, only contains 1 time delay term.

Moreso, the denominator is the same for each ILT. Let's extract it from one of the ILT, in order to apply **partial fraction expansion**.:

```py
# select the first ILT, extract the numerator and denominator of its expression
num1, den = fraction(ilt[0].args[0])
display(num1, den)
```

[image]

The denominator is already in canonical form: the coefficient of s^2 is 1. We are going to find the roots of the denominator:

```py
rr = roots(den)
rr
```

[image]

The keys of the resulting dictionary contains the roots, the values are the multiplicities. We can rewrite the denominator with the newly found roots:

```py
terms = [(s - r)**m for r, m in rr.items()]
new_den = prod(terms)
new_den
```

[image]

You can verify that `new_den` is equal to `den` with: `den.equals(new_den)`.

Now, for each root we create a corresponding symbol:

```py
import string
coeff_symbols = [Symbol(t) for t in string.ascii_uppercase[:len(rr)]]
coeff_symbols
```

[image]

The goal is to rewrite the expression inside the ILT as a summation of rational functions. Note that I'm following step-by-step the procedure explained in the book linked above:

```py
rat_func = sum(c / t for c, t in zip(coeff_symbols, terms))
rat_func
```

[image]

Let's multiply each addend with the denominator:

```py
tmp = sum(t * new_den for t in rat_func.args)
tmp
```

[image]

At this point, we equate this temporary expression to the coefficient of the numerator inside an ILT term, exluding the time-delays (the exponentials).
We loop over the roots, substitute them one by one into the expression, solve for the corresponding symbols. The goal is to create a substitution dictionary.

For the first ILT:

```py
eq1 = Eq(-5, tmp)
eq1
```

[image]

```py
sd1 = {}
for r, symb in zip(rr.keys(), coeff_symbols):
    sd1[symb] = solve(eq1.rewrite(Add).subs(s, r), symb)[0].nsimplify()
sd1
```

[image]

```py
expr1 = (num1 / -5) * rat_func.subs(sd1)
expr1
```

[image]

We can verify that this expression equals the one inside the first ILT with: `expr1.equals(ilt[0].args[0])`.

Now, we do the same for the second ILT term:

```py
eq2 = Eq(5, tmp)
sd2 = {}
for r, symb in zip(rr.keys(), coeff_symbols):
    sd2[symb] = solve(eq2.rewrite(Add).subs(s, r), symb)[0].nsimplify()
num2, _ = fraction(ilt[1].args[0])
num2 = collect_const(num2, 5)
num2
```

[image]

```py
expr2 = (num2 / 5) * rat_func.subs(sd2)
expr2
```

[image]

We can verify that this expression equals the one inside the second ILT with: `expr2.equals(ilt[1].args[0])`.

We are almost done. We need to create new ILT terms containing the new expressions, and replace the old ILT terms:

```py
new_ilt = [old.subs(old.args[0], e) for old, e in zip(ilt, [expr1, expr2])]
display(*new_ilt)
```

[image]

```py
v_time = v.subs([(old, new) for old, new in zip(ilt, new_ilt)]).doit()
```

The final `doit()` is going to evaluate both ILTs and derivatives. The result is too long to be shown here...

Now, we can generate the plot. Sadly, the `plot` function of SymPy is unable to produce the correct visualization. Hence, I'm going to use [this plotting module](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html):

```py
from spb import plot
plot(v_time, modules="sympy", ylabel="v(t)")
```

[image]